# Parsing a variable datatype to a function which contains a conditional check on the datatype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

To pass a datatype that varies (from an array to an integer) to the same function, and then check against the datatype before changing its value, looking at the below method using instanceof Array is there a better/more efficient way?

```
function foo(x) { 
  if (x instanceof Array) {
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){    
      x[i].bar = '1';
      x[i].baz = '2';       
    }   
  }
  else{
    x.bar = '1';
    x.baz = '2';    
  }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object Array]"`, this is an alternative method, but even yours is good

Comment: In newer browsers -> `Array.isArray(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative (using ECMAScript standard)

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( x ) === '[object Array]' ) {

    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++) {  

      x[i].bar = '1';
      x[i].baz = '2';       
    }  
}
```

[See ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2)

Or if you always want it as an array, but this is not recommended

```
x = [].concat( x );
```

Comment: The first method is what is given in ECMAScript to find the class of an object. the second method, as I said is not recommended because of performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way could also be to split up your function (if that is possible for you):

```
function fooArray(x) { 
    for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){    
        foo(x[i]);   
    }   
}

function foo(x) {
    x.bar = '1';
    x.baz = '2'; 
}
```

This would also apply the DRY principle ("don't repeat yourself") because you don't need to code the same logic (i.e. `x.bar = '1';`) twice.